# Exception in plugin Android Support - IntelliJ IDE FATAL ERRORS

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, android-support-library

Last night I was working normally on my project, and this morning I cant get most of the import plugins to work anyhow.

Already tried to deactivate the instant run, invalidate caches, updating IntelliJ, and "clean project" is not going forward.

See the msg:

Android Studio Exception in plugin Android Support

```
No system resource manager for module: app com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:140) at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getPropertiesImpl(NlProperties.java:95) at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.lambda$getProperties$0(NlProperties.java:83) at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.lambda$runReadActionInSmartMode$0(DumbService.java:94) at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.lambda$runReadActionInSmartMode$1(DumbService.java:138) at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.compute(ReadAction.java:47) at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:131) at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:94) at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.property.NlProperties.getProperties(NlProperties.java:83) at com.android.tools.idea.common.property.PropertiesManager.lambda$setSelectedComponents$1(PropertiesManager.java:243) at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my issue with this 2 steps.

1) Delete every "gradle" folder in every module inside of the project

2) Click on "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"

If this not work then see below link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html

Comment: I tried it, it didn't fix it. Thank you. I'll read the link to see if i can find an answer to the problem there.

Comment: Absoutely, after it, in Gradle Projects, I "refreshed all gradle projects" and it fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: what do you mean by every gradle folder in every module? can you please explain?